# How can i fix problem with Docker inside AWS Codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, codebuild

I'm doing cicd with codebuild inside aws:

```yaml
version: 0.2

env:
  parameter-store:
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME: /my-app/docker-credentials/username
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: /my-app/docker-credentials/password
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL: /my-app/docker-registry/url
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip install -r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt
  build:
    commands:
      - cd day-14/simple-python-app
      - echo "Building Docker Image"
      - docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest" .
      - docker push "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest"
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "build is successfull"
```

Result:

```
Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:50.898412 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:51.899396 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.543698 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.545694 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src3886999743/src/github.com/iam-veeramalla/aws-devops-zero-to-hero
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.546293 YAML location is /codebuild/readonly/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.546521 No commands found for phase name: install
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.548511 Setting HTTP client timeout to higher timeout for Github and GitHub Enterprise sources
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.548718 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.556163 Decrypting parameter store environment variables
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.862228 Selecting 'python' runtime version '3.11' based on manual selections...
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.862316 Running command echo "Installing Python version 3.11 ..."
Installing Python version 3.11 ...
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:54.908439 Running command pyenv global  $PYTHON_311_VERSION
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:55.899285 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src3886999743/src/github.com/iam-veeramalla/aws-devops-zero-to-hero
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:55.900756 Unable to initialize cache download: no paths specified to be cached
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.002992 Configuring ssm agent with target id: codebuild:855f11d5-6316-4e91-9cca-b79d5346e690
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034096 Successfully updated ssm agent configuration
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034680 Registering with agent
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034694 Phases found in YAML: 4
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034764  BUILD: 4 commands
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034787  POST_BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034791  INSTALL: 0 commands
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.034795  PRE_BUILD: 1 commands
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.035088 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.035099 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.098674 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.100951 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.100965 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.127894 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:07:56.128552 Running command pip install -r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt
Collecting flask (from -r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading flask-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=3.0.0 (from flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading werkzeug-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.1.2 (from flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.1/133.1 kB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.1.2 (from flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting click>=8.1.3 (from flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting blinker>=1.6.2 (from flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading blinker-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0 (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->flask->-r day-14/simple-python-app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Downloading flask-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 99.7/99.7 kB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading blinker-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.9/97.9 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading werkzeug-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 226.7/226.7 kB 28.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (28 kB)
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, click, blinker, Werkzeug, Jinja2, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.3 Werkzeug-3.0.1 blinker-1.7.0 click-8.1.7 flask-3.0.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.3.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.503489 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.503507 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.533618 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.534319 Running command cd day-14/simple-python-app
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.541258 Running command echo "Building Docker Image"
Building Docker Image
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.546309 Running command docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest" .
ERROR: invalid tag "***/***/simple-python-flask-app:latest": invalid reference format
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.735324 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest" . exit status 1
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.738963 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.738979 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest" .. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.765636 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.766233 Running command echo "build is successfull"
build is successfull
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.771025 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/12/30 19:08:13.771038 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

Comment: _ERROR: invalid tag "***/***/simple-python-flask-app:latest": invalid reference format_

Comment: Did you verify the values of the variables used to build your image name/tag?

Comment: What i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to check the documentation around tagging an image. (There are restrictions around capitalization in the image path.)

> The path consists of slash-separated components. Each component may contain lowercase letters, digits and separators. A separator is defined as a period, one or two underscores, or one or more hyphens. A component may not start or end with a separator. While the OCI Distribution Specification supports more than two slash-separated components, most registries only support two slash-separated components.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/

You can also attempt to separate the full tag from the build command to better illustrate that it is a problem with the tag you are trying to apply.

```
docker build -t my-flask-app .
docker tag my-flask-app:latest $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/simple-python-flask-app:latest
```